# Custom command line utility. How?

Tags: api, unix, command-line, sms

Recently, I've released an open-source class - wrapper of API functions available from one of the leading SMS gateway, which provides an HTTP-API access to send an SMS messages.

Now I want to make a custom command line utitity, which can be available for user anywhere in the command line, so he can send SMS just by running console command like this one:

```
$ my_custom_send_sms_command -u your_username -p your_password -k your_api_key 447771234567 'Hello from CLI'
```

Please, explain how this can be done?

Updated:

Class is written in PHP.

Comment: I think you would better provide more constraints: can your class be accessed from e.g. C, from a shell, from Ruby, ...

Comment: What are you actually missing ? You dont know how to parse commandline options or create console app  or what?!

Comment: Be careful with providing a password like that - if you do, then the password can be read by any user on the system. (Using 'ps aux' or /proc, if available). Better to provide a username/password configuration in a file that is readable only by that user, and pass the file as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the PHP CLI package installed. On my Ubuntu VPS I had to run:

```
$ apt-get install php5-cli
```

Check that it's installed:

```
$ /usr/bin/php -v
```

Then, create a file called something like `sendsms.php` with contents similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

  // command line parameters are in the format:
  //     key1 value1 .. keyN valueN number message

  $username = "";
  $password = "";
  $apikey = "";

  // process pairs of arguments up to the last two    
  for ($x = 0; $x < ($argc - 3); $x++)
  {
    if ($argv[$x] == "-u") $username = $argv[$x + 1];
    if ($argv[$x] == "-p") $password = $argv[$x + 1];
    if ($argv[$x] == "-k") $apikey = $argv[$x + 1];
  }
  $number = $argv[$argc - 2];
  $message = $argv[$argc - 1];

  // To do: call the SMS API
  // For now just output the info   
  echo("Username = " . $username . "\r\n");
  echo("Password = " . $password . "\r\n");
  echo("API key = " . $apikey . "\r\n");
  echo("Number = " . $number . "\r\n");
  echo("Message = " . $message . "\r\n");
?>
```

Make sure the file has execute permissions:

```
chmod 755 sendsms.php
```

And then run it from the current folder like this:

```
$ ./sendsms.php -u your_username -p your_password -k your_api_key 447771234567 'Hello from CLI'
```